# HTML list - width issue

Tags: html, css, width, margin, padding

I'd like to ask you guys for your advice. I have the HTML file liked with CSS, everything's ok but when I open this "site" on my localhost, the `<ul></ul>` list it has more width that I defined. I don't see anything bad there. Can you please look at it and tell em what is going on ?

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="sk">
  <head>
    <link href="scripts/google_analytics.js">
    <link href="scripts/facebook.js">
    <link href="scripts/font_Alef.js">
    <link href="scripts/font_Playfair.js">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="templates/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/media_queries.css">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body class="body">
    <header class="header">
        <img src="templates/logo.png">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Niečo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NIEČO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NIEČO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NIEČO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NIEČO</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </header>
    <content class="content">
    </content>
    <footer class="footer">niečo
    </footer>
  </body>
 </html>
```

and here is my index.css file:

```
body {
font-family: "Myriad Pro";
width: 960px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
    }

header {
width: 960px;
height: auto;
display: block;
font-family: 'Alef', sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
    }   

header img {
width: 480px;
height: auto;
float: left;
    }

header ul {
float: left;
width: 960px;
background-color: #EEE;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    }

header ul li {
  float: left;
 width: 192px;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 height: 40px;
    }

a {
 text-decoration: none;
color: #ED1C25;
    }

content {
float: left;
width: 940px;
background-color: #686868;
    height: auto;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
display: block;
padding: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

 footer {
float: left;
width: 960px;
background-color: #ED1C25;
height: auto;   
display: block;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag `<ul>` has a padding value by default.

Set `padding: 0` in css to solve this.

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JYx4B/)

```
header ul {
    padding:0; /* added */
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh :D Thank you.. I thought it's some bug. I'll accept your answer in 10mins and vote up ;)

Comment: It's not a bug, some tags like ul and p have a preset value of padding and/or margin.